# C# Linq finding value

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return the depart number that is not found Employee Table by comparing Department table.

Person Table

```
ID        name   salary     job              commision  DeptID 
--------------------------------------------------------------
P001      Jon       2000      Manager       NULL       1
P002      Skeet     1000      Salesman      2000       1
P003      James     2340      Developer     NULL       2
P004      greed     4500      Developer     NULL       2
P005      Joel      1330      Salesman      1200       1
P006      Deol      5000      Architect     NULL       2
```

Department Table

```
DeptID  DeptName

    1   Management
    2   Software  
    3   ERP
```

**SQL**

```
select DeptId from dept

where deptId not in (select deptid from person)
```

When i try to execute the below code

**LINQ**

```
var qry = from n in context.Persons
          where n.DeptID !=
          (from m in context.Depts select m.DeptId)
           select new { DeptID = n.DeptID };
```

I receive the following error

Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested rephrasing:

```
var q = from m in context.Depts
        where
        !context.Persons.Select(p => p.DeptID).Contains(m.DeptID)
        select new { DeptID = m.DeptID };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var qry = from n in context.Persons
          where n.DeptID !=
          (from m in context.Depts select m.DeptId).FirstOrDefault()
           select new { DeptID = n.DeptID };
```

You are trying to compare DeptID with a collection 1 or more department Ids.  Even if there would only logically be one result for a DeptID, syntactically you need to specify that you want the first hit.

Comment: This question will however not do what the OP has requested, it will take the first row from the Depts table, and return all the deptsIDs from the row Persons that differ from that first one. The tables should be exchanged in the question.

Comment: Good observation.  I was more focused on the exception than the question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds that your DeptID field in SQL is set to allow nulls.  In that case you'd probably want something along the lines of this:

```
var qry = from n in context.Persons
          where n.DeptID.Value !=
          (from m in context.Depts select m.DeptId)
           select new { DeptID = n.DeptID.Value };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like that. I tried to get a list of DeptID's first and then implement a NOT IN with contains :

```
var deptIDs = context.Persons
     .Where( p => !context.Depts
             .Select(d => new {DeptID = d.DeptID})
             .Contains( p.DeptID ) 
            )
     .Select( p => new { DeptID = n.DeptID } );
```